# Fragment getView returns null while testing in Robolectric

Tags: junit, android-fragments, null, fragment, robolectric

1.I want to test the fragments using robolectric framework.i am using android-support-v4.jar    .            onCreateView() method from NewFragment class is not getting called.

===========================================================

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class NewFragmentTest extends Fragment{
private NewFragment newFragment;


public void startFragment(Fragment fragment) {

            FragmentActivity  activity=Robolectric.buildActivity(FragmentActivity.class).create().start().resume().get();
     FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity
     .getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();

     fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment,
     "new fragment");

    //fragmentTransaction.add(fragment, "");
    // fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    newFragment = new NewFragment();
    newFragment.onCreate(null);
    startFragment(newFragment);
}

@Test
public void testFragmentNotNull() {
    Assert.assertNotNull(newFragment);
}

@Test
public void shouldHaveButton() throws Exception {
    TextView textview = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.id_txt);

    assertThat(textview.getVisibility(), equalTo(View.VISIBLE));

}
```

}

```
   When i am running tests its giving below exception.


    java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.askcs.robodemo.NewFragmentTest.shouldHaveButton(NewFragmentTest.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
atorg.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.ja44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(Parent`enter code here`Runner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Deepa - did you get this resolved? I am curious what was going on and how you fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Your getView() returns null, because the fragment haven't added yet. See the code from Robolectric [FragmentTestUtil](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/robolectric/src/main/java/org/robolectric/util/FragmentTestUtil.java).

The method `startFragment()` looks like that:

```
  public static void startFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    buildFragmentManager(FragmentUtilActivity.class)
        .beginTransaction().add(fragment, null).commit();
  }
```

The inner-Class FragmentUtilActivity looks like that:

```
  private static class FragmentUtilActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      LinearLayout view = new LinearLayout(this);
      view.setId(1);

      setContentView(view);
    }
  }
```

And here is the problem. The dev's give the Layout, the ID 1. The `add(Fragment, String)`-method from `FragmentTransaction` says:

> Calls add(int, Fragment, String) with a 0 containerViewId.

So the Fragment, which is placed in `startFragment(Fragment)` is placed in the ID 0. Which isn't there.

***Solution:***

Call the method `startVisibleFragment(Fragment)`. The code looks the same like `startFramgent(Fragment)` but put the fragment in the container 1 (Which is the LinearLayout from FragmentUtilActivity).

Answer (score 0):

Three things stand out:

1. Your testcase should not extend Fragment. That doesn't make any sense.
2. Assuming the FragmentActivity doesn't contain the fragment when starting, you should commit your fragment transaction in startFragment().
3. You don't need to call onCreate on the fragment yourself.

Hope this will help.

Comment: "Your testcase should extend Fragment. That doesn't make any sense." I assume you mean shouldn't, what should it extend?